# AngularJS Nginx Routing issue on Refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nginx

I am building a AngularJS APP and I have routing working for the first layer of routes:

```
ie:
/blah
/blah2
/blah3
```

However, when I get to a more complex route such as:

```
/blah/thing
/blah2/things
/blah3/things
```

These are not routing correctly when refreshing the page. However work perfectly fine when clicking a link to them from the SPA.

I am running nginx with the following conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /home/app/public;
    index index.html;
    server_name dev-app.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html /index.html;
    }
}
```

And here are some example routes:

```
.when('/instances/running', {
    templateUrl : 'pages/instances-running.html',
    controller  : 'instancesController',
    currentPage : 'Running Instances',
})

.when('/instances/stopped', {
    templateUrl : 'pages/instances-stopped.html',
    controller  : 'instancesController',
    currentPage : 'Stopped Instances',
})

.when('/tickets/open', {
    templateUrl : 'pages/tickets-open.html',
    controller  : 'ticketsController',
    currentPage : 'Open Tickets',
})
```

Please let me know if this is something I can fix or something inherently broken.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had to add a / to the front of src="assets/.*" in index.html

```
 <!-- Angular && Angular Modules -->
  <script src="/assets/javascript/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/javascript/angular-datatables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/javascript/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/javascript/angular-aria.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/javascript/angular-chart.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/javascript/angular-jwt.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/javascript/ng-context-menu.min.js"></script>

  <!-- App JS && App Modules -->
  <script src="/assets/javascript/app/app.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/javascript/app/app-login.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/javascript/app/app-sessions.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/javascript/app/app-template.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/javascript/app/app-dashboard.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/javascript/app/app-account.js"></script>
```

Comment: OMFG thanks. @tomsowerby yes it so freaking annoying. :(